# How do I find a function $f(x,y)$ such that $\nabla f = \langle y,-x\rangle$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I've been stuck on this problem for a while and I am starting to think that it's not possible. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: What is $\langle y,-x\rangle$? is it a scalar? If yes, what should $\nabla f(x,y)=\langle y,-x\rangle$ mean?

Comment: If it is possible you integrate $f_x$ and what we usually see as a constant term for the 1-variable case becomes a function $h(y)$ in $y$. Then integrate $f_y$ and compare it to $\int f_x$ to find the explicit function $h$. It isn't possible in this case though.

Comment: In other words: Do you mean that $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} f(x,y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y_j} f(x,y) = \langle -x,y \rangle$$
for all $i$ and $j$ ?

Comment: @Surb: This is not an inner product. It's a standard notation used in many US textbooks for a vector. And I have no idea what your subscripts are in your second comment. This is a standard 2-variable calculus question.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks, now at least the exercise makes sense to me. But this notation is very weird I think. Very misleading...

Answer (score 1):

If there were such a function $f$, you'd have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -x.$$
Do you know something about $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$?

Comment: The question that I'm trying to answer is what I wrote above, there wasn't any other information offered. So, I'm afraid I don't have any more information about the second partial derivates.

Comment: No, I meant: If you have a reasonable function (such as shows up in a standard multivariable calculus course), is there a fact you've been told relating those two quantities?

Answer (score 1):

The second partial dervitives $f_{xy}, f_{yx}$ are not equal so there is no twice differentiable function $f$ with this property.